# a lot of small objects - OO pasta

Tags: design, c++, design-patterns, object-oriented

In the code I am working on, there are a lot of really small objects like:

```
    class HasFieldLameSetter
    {
     public:
        HasFieldLameSetter(field& p_):m(_p){}
        void set(bool p2)
        {
            m.hasLame = p2;
        }   
       field& m; 
   };
```

Having lots of small classes creates a hard-to-read and complicated "code pasta". Sometimes, reading it is really really hard because I spend a lot of time jumping from file to file to find out that the class did something trivial like in the example setting bool to true.  In addition, those objects are being passed around everywhere by "dependency injection" which makes reading it even more difficult.

**How do I persuade the author of the code to write slightly bigger objects?**

In my opinion too many small objects is just a nightmare for programmers. Am I missing something, or is there a mistake in my thinking? I would be happy to read any papers that might change my point of view.

Comment: This is very subjective and also depends on the situation. Such decomposition and DI will later allow to inject a more complex implementation than the most trivial one. This may or may not be over-engineered, but that's hard to tell without context.

Comment: It's what you end up with when you follow diatribes like "Single Responsibility Principle" religiously and/or are interface happy. Yes, the code becomes very flexible. Unfortunately, it also becomes unmaintainable because few people can understand it.

Comment: Is code pasta a more elegant version of spaghetti code?

Comment: @mclark1129 From this jargon site, [Pasta Code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PastaCode) is an overarching category. [Ravioli Code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RavioliCode) is an OOP version of spaghetti code.

Answer (score 4):

Could I agree with it? Not often.

It is universally excepted best practice that an object have one, and only one responsibility to change (Single Responsibility Principle). For something like this, the code very likely needs to be very granular in order to compose these little teeny objects into more meaningful things.

It is also very common in older C++ and Java where the tiny objects are essentially functors/delegates/function objects, but the language does not support nice syntax to cut down on this sort of boilerplate.

A bunch of tiny objects can get over-engineered or "too" abstracted, but it's not a nightmare and occasionally necessary. I'd rather have too small objects than too large any day.

Comment: The only thing I would add, is that at first its going to be disorientating, but when you have grasped how the code is organised, it makes it much more maintainable